# Package moby-runc-*+azure-2.x86_64.rpm is not signed While Installing Docker

Tags: docker, centos, yum

I am trying to install **Docker** on Centos machine using the installer script https://get.docker.com/ with the following command

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

but failing with error message

```
Package docker-ce is obsoleted by moby-engine, trying to install moby-azure-2.x86_64 instead
Package moby-runc-1.0.0~rc10+azure-2.x86_64.rpm is not signed
```

I have tried different approaches but end up getting the same error.

Comment: Is it similar to https://forums.docker.com/t/centos-install-problems/96943? (Microsoft packages previously installed regarding Azure)

Comment: See also https://blog.vizuri.com/docker-swarm-setup-with-azure-docker-17.03-step-by-step-part-2-of-3 in case it can help (docker+Azure)